# Parallel distribution using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, parallel-processing

I'm using this code in execute shell block in Jenkins

For server in

```
(echo ${!server_name} | sed "s/,/ /g')
do
ssh @server "wget"
ssh @server "unzip"
ssh @server "mv"
done
```

I need to run this code when I select the server from server list option (8-10 servers) in a parallel mode on Jenkins. Please help me how to achieve that. The process is happening now sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Define a string parameter for your job with name `SERVER_NAMES`. Then use a slightly modified and fixed version of your script:

```
for server in $(echo ${SERVER_NAMES} | sed 's/,/ /g')
do
  ssh $server "wget"
  ssh $server "unzip"
  ssh $server "mv"
done
```

When running your job, specify server names delimited by comma.